# Hamburger icon not showing on screen width less than 500px?

Tags: html, css

I have searched but nothing has helped. I cannot get the hamburger menu to show up. It originally showed correctly when screen width was less than 500px (which is what I wanted) but now it won't and I can't find what change has made it disappear. I feel like its a simple answer but I cannot figure it out.

Link to my pen:  https://codepen.io/idfc/pen/gBdmPK

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #051937, #004d7a, 
    #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12);
    <div class="top">
        <div class="nav-bar">
          <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
          <label for="toggle" class="hamburger">
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
           </label>

              <div class="Logo">Logo</div>
              <div class="nav-links"> 
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Links</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and css;

```
.top {

    background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #051937, #004d7a, 
    #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12);

    }
    .beaker {
    display: none;
    }

    h1 {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    }

    #toggle {
    display: none;
    }
    .Logo {

    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
    }

    a {
    display: none;}


   .hamburger {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;


    }

    .hamburger span {
    display: block;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 5px;


    }

    .calculator {
    display: none;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {



a {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    }

    a:hover {
    color: black;
    }

    .beaker {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px grey;
    } 

    .calculator {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px grey;
    }

    .calculator input {
    background: none ;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #111;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    }

    .calc-buttons {
    font-size: 42px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #111;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .calculator-buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 15px;
    }

    .is-clear {
    grid-column: span 3;
    background-color: blue;
    }

    .is-equals {
    grid-column: span 3;
    background-color: green;
    }
    }
    .hamburger {
    display: none;
    }

.Logo {
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.words {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using the `display: none` property on the `.hamburger` class, line 123. Remove that and it will appear.

To hide above screen size of 500px:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I do not want it to show up if the screen is wider than 500px. My goal was to have it there for mobile size screens while hiding the links until the screen is wider than 500px.

Comment: eclipsis, that is what i have on line 50 and 51. Does that not control everything i have below it? Other items work like they should, i.e. I have an image that is display:none at the smaller size window but shows up when you resize to above 500px width, thats exactly what i am trying to do with the hamburger.

Comment: You closed the @media query with a } before .hamburger on line 122. Delete the bracket above .hamburger and place it below .hamburger.

Comment: Oh , got it. Thank you!